# Elm: Decode Json to a simple record structure

Tags: elm

Struggling to find the right way to complete my Decoder. I start with data of the form

```
[{_id:'interests', [{obj1}, {obj1}]}
,{_id:'countries', [{obj2}, {...}]} 
,{_id:'sections', [{obj3}, {...}]}]
```

I want to get to a `Decoder Summary` where

```
type alias Summary =
    { sections : List Section
    , interests : List Interest
    , countries : List Country
    }
```

So far, the best I've been able to get to is an output of this sort:

```
[ Interests (List Interest), Countries (List Country), Sections (List Section)]
```

but that still requires some rather brittle pattern matching (relying upon a consistent order of the array **and is therefore very problematic with 0.16**). For that I use

```
summaryItemDecoder : String -> Decoder SummaryInfo
summaryItemDecoder item =
    let dec =
        case item of
            "sections" -> Json.map Sections sectionsDecoder
            "interests" -> Json.map Interests interestsDecoder
            "countries" -> Json.map Countries countriesDecoder
    in ("data" := dec)

listSummaryDecoder : Decoder (List SummaryInfo)
listSummaryDecoder =
    ("_id" := string) `Json.andThen` summaryItemDecoder
    |> list
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/simonh1000/eu-transparency-register/blob/master/src/Summary/SummaryDecoder.elm). Grateful for some final tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fold the list of information into a Summary.

```
type Interest = Interest
type Section = Section
type Country = Contry

type Info =  Interests (List Interest) | Countries (List Country) | Sections (List Section) 


type alias Summary =
    { sections : List Section
    , interests : List Interest
    , countries : List Country
    }

emptySummary : Summary
emptySummary = 
    { sections = []
    , interests = []
    , countries = []
    }


toSummary : List Info -> Summary
toSummary xs = 
  let 
    insert info sum =
      case info of 
        Sections ss -> { sum | sections = ss }
        Interests is -> { sum | interests = is }
        Countries cs -> { sum | countries = cs } 

  in
    List.foldl insert emptySummary xs

infoList : List Info
infoList = []

summary = toSummary infoList
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do much better; you are attempting to parse a format that can express things you cannot represent in your types, so your only option is to fail.

To satisfy the pattern matching gods, perhaps drop an `otherwise` clause in featuring the `fail` decoder? (http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Json-Decode#fail)

Comment: Thanks, I have indeed added a coverall pattern, but really hope I can find a more flexible output